# I refreshed myself(was refreshed?) by a cup of tea

Tags: phrase-usage

Which is the correct phrase to use ?

Is it

> I refreshed myself by a cup of tea.

Or

> I was refreshed by a cup of tea.

Answer (score 1):

The second is good, but the first should be

> I refreshed myself **with** a cup of tea.

Apart from that you can use either one.

Comment: I don't think it's "ungrammatical to use ***by*** in this context. It's just the more common choice of preposition where the following element is a noun phrase

Comment: @FumbleFingers true, but as another native speaker, some of my answers here follow what I *feel* to be the right way to say things. I didn't say it is "ungrammatical" as you quote!

Comment: _I refreshed myself **by** a cup of tea_ is grammatical, but if I heard someone say it, I would think they meant that they washed their face whie standing next to a hot beverage.

Answer (score 1):

The reflexive form ("I refreshed myself") is grammatical, but it implies that it was specifically my plan to have the tea. If somebody offered me tea, I would be much more likely to say "I was refreshed".

Comment: When I looked at this question yesterday I was so preoccupied by/with the "nonstandard" choice of preposition I didn't really even *notice* that the actual issue being queried concerns reflexive/passive verb forms. But of course you're quite right.